# How to identify and re-establish the PostgreSQL connection based on the PostgreSQL server status?

Tags: postgresql

A PostgreSQL connection will be established once the project started running.
The same connection is used by multiple threads for database operations (insertion,selection etc.).

The connection will be gone once the server is down.

Then how to identify it and re-establish the connection as soon as the server is up?

Comment: That depends a lot on the client API you are using. Please tell us more.

Comment: A connection isn't meant to be shared among several threads. Doing that will corrupt your client. A better approach is to open a connection whenever you run a query, and close it when the query is done.

Comment: I thought to give a connection check before each database operation and create a connection if not exists.But there is a chance for too many open connection exception. @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: If you are using a thread-safe API, there is no problem with multiple threads sharing a database connection **as long as they don't attempt to use it at the same time**.

Comment: When I restart my postgres server, I am getting , **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command.**

How can I  automatically re-connect to the restarted database? @Laurenz Albe

Comment: Catch that error, close the connection (ignoring the errors) and open a new one. Repeat until successful. Pause some seconds between connection attempts.